# Error while Installing windowbuilder on eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a newbie in java. I am having problems in installing windowbuilder. It said:

> windowbuilder was not able to show GUI & Version 4.6 is not present
>   in[3.7,3.8,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: how to fix your problem without your codes?

Comment: I m having problem in installing. the problem is not the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to re-install eclipse. I do use window builder with Eclipse neon, and i didn't get problems with the instalation.

Greatings.

Comment: Thz, Xavier.  i'll try reinstalling.